# Register all the implemented class of an generic interface on the basis of generic data type using factory in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm working with Autofac and trying to register all implemented classes of a generic interface IMock by providing a factory for object creation based on the T data type. I want to be able to resolve any implemented class at runtime.

Here's the simplified interface and classes:

```
public interface IMock<in TRequest>
{
}
public class MockDerived : IMock<int>
{
 public MockDerived()
 {
 }
}

public class MockComponent
{
 public MockComponent()
 {
 }
}

public class MockDerived2 : IMock<string>
{
 private readonly MockComponent _mockComponent;
 public MockDerived(MockComponent mockComponent)
 {
  _mockComponent = mockComponent
 }
}
```

I have a registration function that I want to use:

```
registerFactory(Type T, Func<Func<Type, object>, Type, object> dependencyFactory)
{
  //Autofac registration
}
```

I'm trying to make the registration call as follows:

```
register.registerFactory(typeof(IMock<>, (func,type) => 
{
  var request = type.GetGenericArgument()[0];
  if(request == typeof(int))
  {
   return MockDerived();
  }
  elseif(request ==typeof(string))
  { 
   return MockDerived2(MockComponent(func(typeof(MockComponent)));
  }
});
```

Can it be registered without using RegisterGeneric?

TIA

Comment: *Can it be registered without using RegisterGeneric* What is "RegisterGeneric"?

Comment: RegisterGeneric is a property of autofac builder to register generic interface implementations.